# How to read "fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);"

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build a web application using PHP and I am using [Memcached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) for storing user data from the database.

For example, let’s say that I have this code:

```
 $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id";
$stmt   = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id));
$user   = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I am not really sure how to read the `$user` variable and get the data out of it. I will need to be able to read the email and password column.

How does this work?

Comment: Use `print_r($user);` to view the contents returned

Comment: It returns an array, so does that mean I just read it a $user['password']?

Comment: @PHPDEV: Yep.  Exactly :)

Comment: Thank you everyone. My knowledge of PDO was not very good and now I fully understand how to read this stuff.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns a row from the result set. The parameter [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) tells PDO to return the result as an associative array.

The array keys will match your column names. If your table contains columns 'email' and 'password', the array will be structured like:

```
Array
(
    [email] => 'youremail@yourhost.com'
    [password] => 'yourpassword'
)
```

To read data from the 'email' column, do:

```
$user['email'];
```

and for 'password':

```
$user['password'];
```

Comment: How can I get the row count from the returned data?

Comment: @PHPDEV you don't actually need a row count

Comment: @George Cummins : sorry for seeing and contradicting your comment years after:rowcount() is only to count affected rows (insert, update, delete). To count result sets, it may work with some databases (like mysql), but there's no guarantee at all, see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php.
Use `fetchAll()` then count array entries with `count()`, or if the count is the only needed value, query for a `select count (*)`.

Answer (score 18):

Loop through the array like any other associative array:

```
while($data = $datas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print $data['title'] . '<br>';
}
```

or

```
$resultset = $datas->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>' . $resultset . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 7):

Method

```
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

returns a **dictionary**. You can simply get email and password:

```
$email = $user['email'];
$password = $user['password'];
```

Other method

```
$users = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

returns a **list** of a **dictionary**

Comment: How does this better than a 4-year old accepted answer to this question?

Comment: Instead of the word "array", it is preferable to use the words "list" and "dictionary".

Comment: "Associative array" is the proper word for a "dictionary" :)

Comment: Given that we're specifically talking about PHP, the terms `list` and `dictionary` are entirely and unequivocally incorrect. PHP has neither lists nor dictionaries. It has arrays, and associative arrays.

Answer (score 4):

`PDO:FETCH_ASSOC` puts the results in an array where values are mapped to their field names.

You can access the `name` field like this: `$user['name']`.

I recommend using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. It fetches fields in an object and you can access like this: `$user->name`

Comment: *Why* do you recommend that? Why is it better or what is the advantage? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16846619/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

To read the result you can read it like a simple PHP array.

For example, getting the `name` can be done like `$user['name']`, and so on. The method `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will only return one tuple though. If you want to get all tuples, you can use `fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. You can go through the multidimensional array and get the values just the same.

Comment: It's not "like an array", it *is* an array.  P.S. `tuple` is not a PHP term :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Design Pattern "table-data gateway"

```
class Gateway
{
    protected $connection = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_users", 'root', '');
    }

    public function loadAll()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
        $rows = $this->connection->query($sql);

        return $rows;
    }

    public function loadById($id)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ' . (int) $id;
        $result = $this->connection->query($sql);

        return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php //
    }
}
```

#### Print all row with column 'user_id' only

```
$gateway  = new Gateway();
$users    = $gateway->loadAll();

$no = 1;
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    echo $no . '. ' . $key . ' => ' . $value['user_id'] . '<br />';
    $no++;
}
```

#### Print user_id = 1 with all column

```
$user = $gateway->loadById(1);

$no = 1;
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    echo $no . '. ' . $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
    $no++;
}
```

#### Print user_id = 1 with column 'email and password'

```
$user = $gateway->loadById(1);

echo $user['email'];
echo $user['password'];
```

Answer (score -1):

consider the following code script, will help.

```
$stm = $accountdb->query($sql);
    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $number = $stm->rowCount();        
            $json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                header("Content-type: application/json");
                    echo '{"total" : "' . $number . '","records" : ' . $json . '}';
```