# fullCalendar.js defaultView: 'agendaDay' shows events in all-Day section

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, fullcalendar

Using fullCalendar.js with defaultView as agendaDay, and getting events as JSON from mysql. The ERROR is that it shows the events in the 'all-Day' section.

I tried this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay == 1) {
    event.allDay = true;
    } else {
    event.allDay = false;
    }
```

I also tried:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
event.allDay = false;
},
```

and also this:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element, view) {
event.allDay = false;
},
```

But I'm stock, still not working.

Here is a WORKING fiddle without JSON: events:

http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/g5gtG/1/

To test, you need to change the event: in the jsFiddle for: events: "events.php",

Here is the events.php file

```
<?php
// List of events
 $json = array();

 // Query that retrieves events
 $requete = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id";

 // connection to the database
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }

 // Execute the query
 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 // sending the encoded result to success page
 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

and here is the mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE `evenement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `allDay` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;

INSERT INTO `evenement` (`id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `url`, `allDay`) VALUES
(24, 'testing defaultView with agendaDay and JSON event', '2014-01-07 08:30:00', '2014-01-07 09:30:00', '', 1);
```

Any help to get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your returned JSON in browser console.

Comment: I can see the the rendered event "not in allDay slot" in your jsfiddle, can you edit your question and post your returned JSON in browser console, please.

Comment: @Henrique C. Hi Henrique, Here is the JSON: http://eggings.com/fullcalendar-1.6.4/events.php and here the code in action: http://eggings.com/fullcalendar-1.6.4/default.php. So, in the 1st load you see the event in the all-Day area. If you click on 'month' & then on 'day', the event is in there right place. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry Sebastian is it possible for you to include [ButtonText](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/buttonText/) to be able to navigate in calendar? just to see if in day view the event is rendered ok.

Comment: Btw why don´t you set in the event's JSON "allDay":true or false already?

Comment: @Henrique C. Thanks Henrigque, I added the ButtonText, but it's not showing. When you say in the JSON, you mean in the database? allDay is 0, and it's a tinyInt, so if I put false, it changes to 0. what am I doing wrong ? ;o)

Comment: Btw its showing, the buttons ;)

Comment: Yes, I had to load a different version, this the previous one was not behaving as before ;o) I sent you an email in case you want me to send you the zip file with the code. but I think it's a bug in the fullcalendar.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok i added some code to your JsFiddle to show buttons prev,next:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="prev" id="prevbutton" />
<input type="button" value="next" id="nextbutton"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**JS**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'agendaDay',
header: {
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
year: 2014,
month: 0,
day:7,
buttonText: {
    prev: '&lt;',
    next: '&gt;'
},
events: [
    {
        title: 'testing defaultView with agendaDay and JSON event',
        start: '2014-01-07 11:00',
        allDay: false
    }
]
});

$('#prevbutton').click(function() {
calendar.fullCalendar('prev');
});

$('#nextbutton').click(function() {
calendar.fullCalendar('next');
});
```

Now for your **JSON** you have to manage in your PHP to get the json string like this

```
[{"id":"24","title":"testing with defaultView: agendaDay, not showing in Day","start":"2014-01-09 08:30:00","end":"2014-01-09 09:30:00","url":"","allDay":false}]
```

Use

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

to see if your string is correct, and you must convert the 0 and 1 values for allDay from DATABASE in your PHP not in client side.

**EDIT**

Following the bellow conversation...

You misunderstood my point Sebastian that was for you to get contents of PDO::FETCH_ASSOC in PHP and convert that into a normal PHP associative array and it would be in this fase of conversion when building the normal PHP array that you would change the value of allDay.

Based on that link you could access the returned row that is in fact an associative array like we all know from PHP and change allDay value from 0 to false for example.

Only then you would use json_encode() and send it back to fullcalendar.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I changed in events.php this final line: echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); for yours 
 var_dump(json_decode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))); but gives me a Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/clients/client2/web24/web/fullcalendar-1.6.4/events.php on line 21
NULL

Comment: Here this will help ;) [How to see inside PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc) and then try using this by creating a PHP array and then use this PHP array to your var_dump(json_decode($newPHPArray));

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I used print_r(json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))); (as suggested, and tried other suggestions there) but still the JSON comes as allDay:0 and not allDay:false. But I don't think the problem is there. I also tried to "hack" the result, and just pass: allDay=false; and still first shows in the allDay area.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't think the problem is the JSON, because if I choose to see the month instead of the day, it works fine. The problem happens when I want to see the day first, which is what I need ;o)

Comment: Check edit Sebastian, if you need me to build the code i will ;)

Comment: Hi Henrique, Your explanation seems good, but it's too complex for me to understand. I tried to contact you via your domain. but I don't know how to send you an email.

Comment: Sent you an email Sebastian to continue conversation, but after the solving this question it must posted here after.