# How to display the results of a MySQL query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function in a linked file:

```
function getIndividualHerpInfo($herpID) {
    $sql = "SELECT COLOR, PRICE
    FROM HERPES
    WHERE ID = $herpID";
    return DBIface::connect()->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I can call on this function from any other page in the website. What I want to do is to be able to use the results of this query individually. Like, echo the color of one herp, and, in another place, echo the price of the herp.

I tried looking online for how to do this, but I was unable to find something to help me with the structure of this particular function. Please tell me how to use the results of such a query individually in another file? Thanks.

Comment: You're using PDO, but you are not using prepared statements and instead are leaving yourself open to injection attacks. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read fetch(PDO::FETCH\_ASSOC);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc)

Comment: ElGavilan you make me laugh... Thank you sir.

Comment: siride It's just for a university assignment, so I'm not bovvered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
$data = getIndividualHerpInfo(1);

echo $data['COLOR'];
echo $data['PRICE'];
```