# rename key of newly added element in associative array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a array thats returned from a php query. result is like this.

okay, here is the for loop just after the select was done

> ```
>   $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
>   $arraySize = sizeof($row);
>
>   for($x = 0; $x < $arraySize;$x++)
>     {
>
>         // Gets rid of all the numeric KEY values
>         $max = sizeof($row[$x])/2;
>         for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++)
>         {
>             unset($row[$x][$i]);
>         }
>
>         $row[$x][] = false; // appends a boolean value for the tick box in datatables
>         $row['select'] = $row['9'];
>         unset($row['9']);
>
>         $json[] = $row[$x];
>     }
> echo json_encode($json);
> ```

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [uuid] => 365
                [name] => August_Kidsmeals.mp4
                [title] => 
                [path] => file://C:/wamp/www/chopperv2/video/library/
                [duration] => 00:30:00
                [uploaded_date] => 2014-07-22
                [uploaded_by] => admin
                [keyword] => 
                [comment] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [uuid] => 368
                [name] => August_breakfast.mp4
                [title] => 
                [path] => file://C:/wamp/www/chopperv2/video/library/
                [duration] => 00:30:00
                [uploaded_date] => 2014-07-22
                [uploaded_by] => admin
                [keyword] => 
                [comment] => 
            )
    )
```

Now I want to push a extra element onto the array ( 'selected' ) before sending it via AJAX to a datatable.

I would like to custom name the KEY of the pushed element, but Im having difficulties doing this.

I have tried this. which works but its numeric.

> $row[$x][] = true;

Its part of a `For loop`. This results in a 'appendation' of `[9] => 1`

I tried to rename the `[9]` with something like this

> ```
> $row['select'] = $row['9'];
> unset($row['9']);
> ```

but to no avail. Please can someone slap me in the right direction.

**This should be the result**

> ```
>  [0] => Array
>         (
>             [uuid] => 365
>             [name] => August_Kidsmeals.mp4
>             [title] => 
>             [path] => file://C:/wamp/www/chopperv2/video/library/
>             [duration] => 00:30:00
>             [uploaded_date] => 2014-07-22
>             [uploaded_by] => admin
>             [keyword] => 
>             [comment] => 
>             [select] => 1      //  <<------    I WANT THIS
>         )
> ```

Comment: Show the desired result array

Comment: i think you have to provide more code, it's hard to guess from here how you're doing it

Comment: What is `$x`? Where are you getting this `selected` from? You need to narrow down your question more.

Comment: Where has the "rename key"-part gone though?

Comment: So you just want to add an item to your current array?

Comment: Yes, append a element with a custom KEY name.

Comment: 2 ways to do it.. At the moment you get this array, I guess it comes from the DB.. Or when you retrieve the original array, just loop it and add it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121548/how-to-push-both-value-and-key-into-array-php

Comment: does this came from `PDO` select? use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` so that you dont need to unset numeric key values

Comment: Btw: Have a look at PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, e.g. at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach should suffice and use `&` reference on each copy:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // no need to unsetting numeric indexed values, all are in associative now
foreach($rows as &$row) {
    $row['selected'] = true;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks but thats not the point. Yes is is a `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, but I want to append a custom `KEY => VALUE` at the end of each array.
The `'SELECT'` key that I want to append is NOT returned with the query

Comment: @mornenel wait did you even tried this? this appends it on the end of each array

Comment: @mornenel sure no prob

Answer (score 0):

Just add the element to the desired row in your loop:
(And maybe, if you olny want that selected row to the whole result)

```
if(9 == $x) {
 $row[$x]['select'] = 1;
 $result = $row[$x];
 break;
}
```