# How to create multidimensional array with name of columns in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have this query and I would like to create multidimensional array. I tried this:

```
$columns = array("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4");
$query = "SELECT " . implode(",", $columns) . " FROM my_table";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();

$data = array();
while ($row = $stm->fetch()) {
    $nestedData = array();

    for ($i = 0, $m = count($columns); $i < $m; $i++) {
        $value = $row[$columns[$i]];
        $nestedData[] = empty($value) === false ? $value : "";
    }

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

I get something like this:

```
[["value11","value12","value13","value14"],
["value21","value22","value23","value24"], etc]
```

I would like to have there also names of columns (like this):

```
[["col1":"value11","col2":"value12","col3":"value13","col4":"value14"],
["col1":"value21","col2":"value22","col3":"value23","col4":"value24"], etc]
```

Could anybody help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read fetch(PDO::FETCH\_ASSOC);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "fetch_style" properties:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

And use 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
$columns = array("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4");
$query = "SELECT " . implode(",", $columns) . " FROM my_table";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is that PDO returns an associative array. This can easily be achieved by doing this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or if you want this to be default for all your queries, you can create your connection that way:

```
$conn = new PDO($connStr, $usr, $pass, [
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
]);
```

For more information or options, read the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Then you need:

```
$nestedData[] = empty($value) === false ? $value : "";
```

needs to look like

```
$nestedData[$column_name] = empty($value) === false ? $value : "";
```

where `$column_name` is the name of the field. Look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to work out how to get the field names that you need.

Something like this might work:

```
foreach ($row AS $key => $value)
{
    $nestedData[$key] = empty($value) === false ? $value : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead for loop you can do foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key=>$element){
    $nesteddata[$key] = $element;
}
```