# convert from mysqli to pdo

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

I'm a rookie in MYSQL PDO, and I'm trying to convert from SQLi to PDO.

I have solved most of the line but one of the line I'm still getting errors after I changed to PDO.

please see code....

```
 <?php session_start();  include_once("../cs/db.php");

 //echo 'lll'.$_SESSION['user']; if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

 if(isset($_SESSION['cart_id'])){

 $cart_id_session =

 $_SESSION['cart_id']; 

 }else{

 $q_fetch_cart_id = $conn->query("select cart_id from cart where user_id = 

  '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

 $cart_id_set = $q_fetch_cart_id ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $cart_id_session = $cart_id_set[0];

 $_SESSION['cart_id'] = $cart_id_session;}}

 ?>
```

As you can see on last three lines, I changed to (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and that line have solved but then next line where it said

> $cart_id_session = $cart_id_set[0];

I'm getting errors said

Undefined offset: 0

Is this has to do with PDO! if so what is correct code is!

Many thanks for your help.
AM

Comment: The associative array will contain strings, not numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc/16858666

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting anything, can someone write correct code for me to understand please;.

Comment: Doing this `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` means you have to do this `$cart_id_set['cart_id']`.

Comment: If you just have `fetch()`, you could do either `$cart_id_set[0]` or `$cart_id_set['cart_id']`

Comment: You can also do `$cart_id_set = $q_fetch_cart_id ->fetchColumn();` and then `$cart_id_set` will be the cart_id

Comment: To see what the returned array contains, try `var_dump($cart_id_session)`