# Creating Objects Within Objects from MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am doing a basic SELECT like this using PHP and PDO:

```
SELECT user_id, account, value FROM accounts;
```

I get something like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| USER ID | ACCOUNT | VALUE |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 12      | abc     | 12.00 |
| 12      | def     | 98.00 |
| 21      | ghi     | 25.00 |
| 32      | qwe     | 32.00 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

I would like it to be saved to an array/object in this format:

```
[12] => Array
    (
       [abc] => "12.00"
       [def] => "98.00"
    )
[21] => Array
    (
       [ghi] => "25.00"
    )
[32] => Array
    (
       [qwe] => "32.00"
    )
```

So that I could later do something like this:

```
$myArray['12']['def'] // "98.00"
```

I was trying to come up with the most efficient way to handle this. I will have the potential of having 100s/1000s of users that each will have about 5-10 accounts.

I tried using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)` but that is not allowed. Although the manual says they are often used together?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc/16858666. I would use this and then build a new array in your desired setup

Comment: I think you want `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP`

Comment: @AbraCadaver - That does not provide the desired results.

Comment: @Bleach - I was hoping there was a more PDO-related solution.

Comment: The answer in the linked question references PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.  Which is what I woild use here. Then use that array to build your new one.

Comment: @Bleach - Do you have any suggestions as to how to use the FETCH_ASSOC array to build the new one in the format I am looking for? I am kind of at a loss.

Comment: Use the fetch assoc, vardump the array..add that results yo your question and ill help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple loop that fills in the appropriate array elements.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $results[$row['user_id']][$row['account']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: Check it once more

Comment: This indeed does exactly what I needed. I was way overthinking it and making it far more complicated than it needed to be. Thank you, Barmar!

Answer (score -1):

Re-Write the SQL code as :-

```
$sql = "select *
        from accounts
        where user_id in (select distinct user_id
                          from accounts)" ;
```

Comment: That `WHERE` clause makes no difference.

Comment: How can a row not match that condition?